# Passing value from one controller to another controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass $valPrev from AddressController.php to FrontController.php. I am using with function to pass variable.

**Front Controller.php**

```
 public function index2($valPrev){
            $shop=Products::all();
            $valPre = Input::get('valPrev');


    dd($valPrev);
            $garma = Products::where('season','=','Summer')->take(4)->get();
            $sarma = Products::where('season','=','Winter')->take(4)->get();
            $khizan = Products::where('season','=','Autumn')->take(4)->get();
            $bahar = Products::where('season','=','Spring')->take(4)->get();
            $review = Review::orderby('id','desc')->take(2)->get();

            return view('front.index',compact('shop','garma','sarma','khizan','bahar','review'));
        }
```

**AddressController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'fname'=>'required',
        'lname'=>'required',
        'Ttl'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'addressline'=>'required',
        'city'=>'required',
        'pro'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required |regex:/^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$/',

    ]);
    Address::create($request->all());
    $pro=$request->Ttl;

    $proo=$request->pro;

    return redirect('/')->with('valPrev',1);
}
```

Comment: If it's on two different requests, store it in the session.

Comment: Doesn't with() function works as a session

Comment: No, `with()` passes the variable into the view. It does not store it in the session.

Comment: Ok. I try it your way

Comment: @Faiez the `with` method uses session to store the data when redirecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When redirecting, the `with()` method flashes data to the session.

Use `session()` helper to get the data:

```
$valPrev = session('valPrev')
```

Or `Session::get()`:

```
$valPrev = \Session::get('valPrev');
```

Comment: Thanks that helped alot

Answer (score 0):

Using the redirect with "with". The value should be at session. Try using

```
session()
```

Check here for more detail. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods in which you can pass the data to another controller.

1.. by redirecting

2.. with session.

I assume you have a named routes in your application, you can use `route('name', $param)`

secondly, you can achieve this by saving data into sessions. Laravel provides a really nice helper to achieve this you can simply save value to session with `session()->set('key','value')`

Hope this helps.